# How to vectorize Matlab code?

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I want to vectorize some piece of matlab code. This is the original code:

```
DelPos=find(q>I);

From=[0 DelPos]+1;
To=[DelPos I+J]-1;

L=cell(J,1);
UC=zeros(1,J);
for j=1:J
    L{j}=q(From(j):To(j));
    if ~isempty(L{j})                      
        UC(j)=sum(r(L{j}));
    end
end
```

And this is my attempt to vectorize it:

```
DelPos=find(q>I);

From=[0 DelPos]+1;
To=[DelPos I+J]-1;

L=cell(J,1);
UC=zeros(1,J);

L{1:J}=q(From(1:J):To(1:J));
UC(1:J)=sum(r(L{1:J}));
```

However, it gives an error:

```
The right hand side of this assignment has too few values to satisfy the left hand side.

Error in ParseSolution (line 37)
    L{1:J}=q(From(1:J):To(1:J));
```

**UPDATE:**

I finally substituted cell with 2-dim array, however still cannot vectorize the code:

```
L=zeros(J,3000);
UC=zeros(1,J);
lenr=zeros(1,J);
for j=1:J
    ro=q(From(j):To(j));
    lenr(j)=length(ro);
    L(j,1:lenr(j))=ro;
    if ~isempty(L(j,1:length(ro)))                      
        UC(j)=sum(r(L(j,1:length(ro))));
    end
end
```

My vectorized version is the following, but `ro=q(From(1:J):To(1:J)`) is always substituted by the last J:

```
ro=q(From(1:J):To(1:J));
lenr(1:J)=length(ro(1:J));
L(1:J,1:lenr(1:J))=ro(1:J);                      
UC(1:J)=sum(r(L(1:J,1:length(ro(1:J)))));
```

Comment: Could you use regular arrays rather than cell arrays? They might be better for performance.

Comment: @Divakar: If I simply convert L to an array (L=zeros(J,1)), then this line L(j)=q(From(j):To(j)) returns an error: In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same.

Error in ParseSolution (line 39)
        L(j)=q(From(j):To(j))

Comment: @Divakar: It looks like I cannot switch to arrays, because  q(From(j):To(j)) returns an array, and I cannot save it in L(j).

Comment: @KlausosKlausos can you please provide the example `q` and `I`?

Comment: @brainkz: I is a number, e.g. 1070. q is 1x1070 double array.

Comment: @brainkz: I finally substituted cell with 2-dim array (see my update), however still cannot vectorize the code

Comment: @KlausosKlausos: Do you need `L`? If not, it's fairly straightforward to vectorize this.

Comment: @Jonas: Indeed I need L. However anyway it would be nice to see your solution without L (maybe I can adopt it).

Answer (score 0):

In case you do not need `L`, you can vectorize as follows:

```
qSum = [0,cumsum(q)]; %// assumes q is 1-by-n
lenr = To-From+1;
UC = qSum(To+1)-qSum(From);
```